# How to write a param with query values of enum type in camel 2.16

Tags: java, apache-camel

I want the param  to be

1. param type to be RestParamType.query
2. dataType as string
3. query values must be an enum of one of these values {Monday,Tuesday,WednesDay}

I have implemented the routeBuilder with params

```
     .param()
        .name("rest").description(" param").type(RestParamType.query).allowableValues("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday").dataType("string")
     .endParam()
```

But the output schema is

```
"parameters" : [ {
      "name" : "rest",
      "in" : "query",
      "description" : "",
      "required" : true,
      "type" : "String"
    } ]
```

What I wanted is

```
"parameters" : [ {
      "name" : "rest",
      "in" : "query",
      "description" : "",
     "type": "string",
        "required": true,
        "enum": [
          "Monday",
          "Tuesday",
          "Wednesday",
        ]
      },
```

How to write the route for this above schema in camel for generating API-Docs using swagger-camel library (refered from [http://camel.apache.org/swagger-java.html]).

Answer (score 0):

Ah yeah unfortunately `allowedValues` was not in use in the generated model. I have logged a ticket to get this included in the next release: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9446

With this change the enums is now included in the generated model.